# Write a name on the cube

Tags: three.js

Can I write a name on the object. Say If I have a cubegeometry can I write my name on the object. And so how to add a text name at background.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an approach which is demonstrated in the following `three.js` example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_canvas

The idea is to use an instance of [THREE.CanvasTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture). It is a special type of texture that uses a canvas element as its data source. If you now draw shapes or text on this canvas, you will see the result mapped on your box geometry. Since you can use `THREE.CanvasTexture` like all other textures, you can also use it as a background texture.

Comment: Can we do it in static

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: write my name on the cube and gift my gf for valentines day...lol

Comment: For such a use case, it's better to use JPG or PNG texture ;)